# Vis JS :: Scroll Network Graph when Using 'dragging' Event

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

I've got a network graph and I need to use the `dragging` event.
This overrides the scroll by dragging and the ability to drag nodes that I also need to preserve.

Is there a way to access the default callback and call it? What other solution would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the **dragging** event and everything worked ok in my case.

You can also try to use the **dragStart** or the **dragEnd** event and see if those fits your case.

my 2 cents